# C++ object and C style cast question

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following code compiled by gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Buffer {
public:
   operator char *() { cout << "operator const * called" << endl; return buff; }
private:
    char buff[1024];
};


int main(int, char**) {
    Buffer b;
    (char *)b;  // Buffer::operator char * is called here

    return 0;
}
```

What I see is that Buffer::operator char * is called on line:

```
(char *)b;
```

Why C style cast calls Buffer::operator char * is called here?

I though that

```
static_cast<char *>(b);
```

should be used in order to invoke explicitly Buffer::operator char *.

Comment: just for the record: This conversion operator is a very bad idea because the conversion's result requires the original object to be alife. Implicit conversions should only be used if the resulting object is independent from the original object. For example, `std::string` doesn't implicitly convert to `const char*` for safety reasons. You have to use the `c_str` function if you're interested in a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had done `(char *)(&b)` it would have been C style cast and `operator char*` will not be called. Here you are trying to cast an object into char*. Since there is no automatic conversion compiler looks for operator char* provided by you. If you had not provided it, you'll get a compiler error saying that `Buffer` can not be converted into `char*`

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a C-style cast decides between `static_cast`, `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` depending on the type of the argument and the target type.

<strike>if you want a C cast, you need to use `reinterpret_cast` explicitly.</strike>

If you don't want the default behavior, specitfy the type of cast you want explicitely.

Answer (score 2):

C++ Standard in 5.4/2 says that:

> An explicit type conversion can be expressed using functional notation (5.2.3), a type conversion operator (`dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `const_cast`), or the *cast* notation.
>
> ```
>    cast-expression:  
>       unary-expression  
>       ( type-id ) cast-expression
> ```

You have cast expression here, which calls user defined cast operator.

Answer (score 2):

C-style casts makes compiler performs `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or some combination of them. To be more precise:

> The conversions performed by
>
> ```
> * a const_cast (expr.const.cast), 
>
> * a static_cast (expr.static.cast), 
>
> * a static_cast followed by a const_cast, 
>
> * a reinterpret_cast (expr.reinterpret.cast), or 
>
> * a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast,
> ```
>
> can be performed using the cast
>   notation of explicit type conversion.
>   The same semantic restrictions and
>   behaviors apply. If a conversion can
>   be interpreted in more than one of the
>   ways listed above, the interpretation
>   that appears first in the list is
>   used, even if a cast resulting from
>   that interpretation is ill-formed. If
>   a conversion can be interpreted in
>   more than one way as a static_cast
>   followed by a const_cast, the
>   conversion is ill-formed

As the rules are bit complicated it's better to avoid C-style casts in order to be sure what exactly is done.

Answer (score 0):

C-style casts in C++ really mean: Hey compiler, why don't you help me out here and figure out how best to convert to the target type? And, the compiler obliges. Here you have a conversion operator specified, which gets called because that's what the compiler thinks is best.

Note, that this neat little trick (of using C-style casts) should not be used until and unless you are absolutely sure of what you are trying to achieve.