# C style casting and readability in C++

Tags: c++, c, casting, readability

Yes I know you shouldn't use C style casts in C++, but in some cases I really think it's a lot more readable if you do, compare these two for example:

```
d = ((double)i * 23.54) / (d + (double)j);

d = (static_cast<double>(i) * 23.54) / (d + static_cast<double>(j));
```

Which one is more readable?

Now on to my main question. Obviously I prefer the upper one, but there is one way to make it even more readable in my opinion:

```
d = (double(i) * 23.54) / (d + double(j));
```

My question here is, will this be less efficient? Will the compiler create more doubles in this case than if they were casted with the other methods, or is it clever enough not to? Is this more or less bad than typical C-style casts?

Comment: While in C++ use C++ casts and refrain from using C style casts on C++ objects. Not a duplicate but bit related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635897/c-object-and-c-style-cast-question

Comment: +1 nice question, I think I have never used double(i), and I admit it's quite readable.

Comment: static_cast<...> is a lot easier to search for.

Comment: You do not need any casts above if `i` and `j` are `int` and `d` is `double`.

Comment: Ah right, I understand. But let's say it's needed just for the sake of argument or readability. Bad example on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler will "create" exactly the same number of doubles. There is no practical difference between casting to and constructing primitive numeric types.

Comment: While I highly appreciate the other answers and the info I've gotten in this thread, this is the only answer that actually answered my specific question, so I'll mark it as the answer ;)

Answer (score 15):

They're all unreadable. You should write:

```
d = (i * 23.54) / (d + j);
```

Comment: @R.. +1 for spotting this. :)

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: actually, it doesn't matter. C++ will do the conversion for you and use the most appropriate type. One big advantage of this solution is that if you suddenly updated `d` to be of type `float` or `long double`, then the compiler will still perform the most appropriate conversion while your explicit conversions will need to be changed manually... and some will likely be forgotten.

Comment: Yeah I understood that now. Although I tend to not remember (or be too lazy to really check if it works as I want it or not) so I'll just write out the casts to be on the safe side. Rather safe than sorry as I'm highly unlikely to change the type of d, but might very well mix up where a conversion is and isn't needed (as demonstrated by the example I picked ;) )

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: I've added an answer for the cases where picking the conversion is desirable (to gain precision for example), in short I highly recommend `boost::numeric_cast`, because it checks for overflow / underflow and thus prevents the nasty undefined behavior.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: and it's using casts "just to be safe" that tends to get people into trouble with C-casts: since they're powerful enough to perform conversions that *aren't* safe, you may inadvertently create an expression that will silently go from "over-verbose but correct" to "terribly, tragically wrong" when a type is changed elsewhere...

Comment: For this example you're right, but sometimes you need more precision than default conversions will allow: `(int) (rand() / (double) (RAND_MAX + 1) * n)`

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Your example is bad and outright buggy. If `RAND_MAX` is `INT_MAX`, then `RAND_MAX+1` already overflowed before you cast to double. Replacing `1` with `1.0` would fix the bug and remove the useless cast.

Comment: @R.: You're right!  Parens in the wrong place, embarrassing...  Yes, `1.0` would avoid the need for a cast, but I think `(int) ((rand() / ((double) RAND_MAX + 1) * n)` is better because it's more explicit.

Comment: In relation to this, could someone point me to a page or something that lists when something becomes float and when it becomes int if you don't use explicit casts, e.g; `int + float -> int` and `float + int -> float` (I don't even know if this is true, it's just an example)

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: The rules are actually slightly different for C and C++.  But generally speaking, when 2 operands have different types, smaller types are converted to larger types.  In C++ at least, if either type is `long double`, the other is converted to that; otherwise, if either is `double`, the other is converted to that; otherwise, if either is `float`, the other is converted to that.  If no FP types are involved, there are similar rules for converting to integer types, but they're complicated by the fact that these types can be `unsigned` or not.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Ok thanks, but what if you have one int and one float with the same number of bits? And are these rules always true regardless of what operator is used between the two values or can it differ between for example addition and division?

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: Floating point types always trump integer types.  (That's actually implied by my comment if you read it carefully.)  All binary arithmetic and relational (`<`, `==` etc.) operators operate the same way, converting "up" small-typed arguments.  The result type of arithmetic operators is the common type of the operands after any conversions done on them.  Operands of `%` and the bitwise operators have to be integral.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: So technically the only possible time you want to cast values is when you make a division between two integers, but you don't want to make an integer division? And even then you only need to cast one of them and the other one will be casted automatically? Edit: Or when you have a floating point value and want to make a clean integer operation (as it would otherwise force all other values into float as well).

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha: Those are 2 good examples.  Another would be if you need the extra precision temporarily, e.g. if you have 3 `int` values `a`, `b`, `c` and want to calculate the `int` value of `a * b / c` but `a * b` could overflow an `int`.  In this case you could write `(int) ((long) a * b / c)` (assuming `long` is actually longer than `int`, which is *not* guaranteed).

Comment: Another really important class of examples is when you need to override signedness.

Answer (score 2):

I have already commented on R's answer about letting the compiler pick out the cast, in this particular case.

There are however cases in which you DO want an explicit conversion:

- you want to prevent overflow or increase precision
- you want to check the validity of the conversion

The [Boost Numeric Conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) provides a highly suitable cast here, much better than `static_cast`: **[boost::numeric_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html)**

- no overhead when no check is required (ie casting from a small to a large integer)
- runtime check of the value when required (ie casting from large to small or signed to unsigned)

It's more readable than `static_cast`, since the very nature of the numbers is highlighted, and much safer since it prevents undefined behavior (and portability issues) to kick in.

Comment: Your version, even if you fix the bug, still has bias. Potentially very bad bias, depending on the value of `n`.

Comment: @Matthieu: Read my comment to the other place he posted that example. It's wrong.

Comment: @Matthieu: Tragically that snippet contained the *exact* overflow bug I was trying to avoid...  Here it is again, corrected:

Comment: Example: to get an int in the range 0 - (n-1), use `(int) ((rand() / ((double) RAND_MAX + 1) * n)`. The `(double)` is critical to avoiding integer overflow on many systems where `RAND_MAX` is the largest representable integer. (Why not just `rand() % n`? It's biased.)

Comment: @R.: Could you explain/point to an explanation of this "very bad bias"?  That's news to me.

Comment: @R..: I am not that interested in the bias, truth to be told, more in the overflow / underflow issue, thanks for the comment though since it's always tempting to copy/paste these snippets. I would suppose it's got something to do with the finite precision of doubles (is it 15/16 digits ?) which could lead to large values being unrepresentable faithfully, isn't it ?

Comment: After multiplying by `n`, how many `double` values map down onto each `int` value? If `n` divides `RAND_MAX+1` then the map is `k=(RAND_MAX+1)/n` to one, and each output is equally likely (assuming the original `rand()` had uniform distribution). But if `n` does not divide `RAND_MAX+1` evenly (worst-case: `n` is very large, e.g. `RAND_MAX`), some outputs will have `k` preimages and others will have `k+1` preimages. If `k` is 1 and `k+1` is 2, or even if `k` is 10 and `k+1` is 11, this is pretty bad bias...

Comment: @R.: Yes, but that bias is unavoidable for a O(1) RNG.  (To do better when `n` doesn't divide `RAND_MAX+1` you need a `while` loop that discards some values and tries again.)  This formulation is still much better than `rand() % n` because its expected value remains around `n/2` since the more-probable outcomes are spread as evenly as possible, whereas for `rand() % n` the more-probable outcomes are all located at the low end so it's expected value is skewed strongly downwards.

Comment: @R.: Come to think of it, I would be interested in hearing about either (a) any O(1) RNG that produces lower bias (in terms of expected value, other moments, or any other reasonable criteria) than the one I gave; or (b) any RNG that produces truly unbiased outcomes for any `n` *and* guarantees completion in finite time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why cast functions in C++ are long an unwieldy is by design 
1) in order to show the user that he's probably doing something wrong
2) in cases when they are necessary, attract attention to that piece of code, that it might be doing something dangerous or unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the static_cast one is more readable, because it provides to the reader information about the nature of the cast.